# PyQt5 Terminate the app without hitting any button or clicking on anything

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

```py
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QMainWindow, QLabel, QGridLayout, qApp,
                             QApplication, QWidget, QPushButton)
from PyQt5.QtCore import QSize, Qt   

class HelloWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle("Hello world") 

        centralWidget = QWidget()          
        self.setCentralWidget(centralWidget)   

        title = QLabel("Hello World from PyQt") 
        title.setAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter) # <---

        gridLayout = QGridLayout(centralWidget)          
        gridLayout.addWidget(title,  0, 0)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    mainWin = HelloWindow()
    mainWin.show()
    mainWin.close()
    app.quit()
    sys.exit( app.exec_() )
```

I want the app to be closed "automatically" (without hitting any button or clicking the "x"). I tried `close()` and `app.quit()` however it just closes the window. The app is still running on.
Can you, please, help me to overcome this problem?

Comment: What is `Game`? What does it do? What is going to happen in the for loop? Please provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @musicamante In fact, I think the essence of the Game, and the things that are occurring in the loop are not relevant because I seek some universal solution (some function maybe) to close the app once I don't need it anymore (in this case after the loop execution). Therefore, I just didn't mention these things explicitly. However, if this information will be any helpful the Game is the app created with the use of PyQt5. In the loop I am gathering some data about the game state.

Comment: What `Game` does and what could happen in the loop **is** relevant, and *a lot*. You say that `Game` is "the app created with the use of PyQt5", but an "app" already exists (the QApplication instance), so I can only *suppose* that with that you mean some QWidget based UI that should do something. Then, from your code it seems that `generate_data` is part of a class, we don't know what type of class it is and what it does, nor how it's created. Please, provide a MRE as already requested.

Comment: @musicamante Unfortunately I don't know how to compress it into a small reproducible example because there are different classes that are connected with each other. I can just say what I did. The Game() is launching the UI, it is an ancestor of QMainWindow, there are some widgets on the main window. In the loop I am calling a function make_a_step() wich moves a particle and I am storing the coordinates of that particle in a list. After the steps have been made I would like the app to close itself, without hitting any button or clicking anywhere.

Comment: Then it might be enough to just `close` the window: by default, as soon as the last Qt window is closed, QApplication automatically quits (meaning that `app.exec()` returns).

Comment: @musicamante I tried to use `close` but it just closes the window keeping the app going on and I want to terminate the app. I changed the description of the problem. Can you have a look at it now?

Comment: Calling `app.quit()` before using `app.exec()` won't do nothing...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think I found a solution. Modifying the cod like this gives the desired answer

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QMainWindow, QLabel, QGridLayout, qApp,
                             QApplication, QWidget, QPushButton)
from PyQt5.QtCore import QSize, Qt   

class HelloWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle("Hello world") 

        centralWidget = QWidget()          
        self.setCentralWidget(centralWidget)   

        title = QLabel("Hello World from PyQt") 
        title.setAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter) # <---

        gridLayout = QGridLayout(centralWidget)          
        gridLayout.addWidget(title,  0, 0)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    mainWin = HelloWindow()
    mainWin.show()
    timer = QTimer()
    timer.timeout.connect(lambda: app.quit())
    timer.start(100)
    sys.exit( app.exec_() )
```

The problem here is that we don't have any Python events set up yet. So our event loop never churns the Python interpreter and so our signal delivered to the Python process is never processed. Therefore, our Python process never sees the signal until we hit the exit button of our Qt application window. (source: https://machinekoder.com/how-to-not-shoot-yourself-in-the-foot-using-python-qt/)

Comment: Sorry but your code doesn't have a lot of sense (nor your edit to the original question). A QTimer doesn't care about what would happen in the HelloWindow: you said that it should "move some particles", but it's not clear how those particles are moved (do they move using some timed event? should the movements be processed one "frame" at a time?) nor how much time should that movement take. If you want to show some kind of animation and close a window as soon as the animation is ended, you should look for the [Animation Framework](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/animation.html).

Comment: @musicamante Well, that is what I really meant when I said that I seek a universal solution. Therefore, in the first place I didn't describe the loop or anything that the function/app should do. I don't want QTimer to care about my program, I want it to be closed as soon as I am done with it (which this solution seems to do).  Anyway, it works for me. Thank you for your contribution, sorry to disturb you.

Comment: There is no "universal solution", because it all depends on what those classes do. In your case it probably works because the single shot timer times out "as soon as possible" (meaning that it "leaves" time to all classes to, at least, complete their `__init__`), but I wouldn't suggest you this kind of approach. Unfortunately, given your example (which is too "abstract" to begin with) it's really hard to be able to correctly help you: while, right now, it seems to work, I'm afraid that you might face some problems at some progress in the development of your program.